# record from two microphones - ios

Tags: ios, audio

IOS:
Can I record from two IPhone microphones at the same time?

An answer from 2014 says it is impossible:
[Two-channel recording on the iPhone/iPad: headset + built-in mic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618707/two-channel-recording-on-the-iphone-ipad-headset-built-in-mic)

Has anything changed since?

More specificlly - 
I want to record video-sound from back microphone, and at the same time still listen to button microphone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record from all 3 microphones in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827263/record-from-all-3-microphones-in-ios)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Is it possible to record from multiple microphones at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420918/ios-is-it-possible-to-record-from-multiple-microphones-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You need a multi-input device such as a bluetooth compatible mixer.

There is only one sound input stream on the iPhone and that is either the receiver or the 3rd ring on headphone jack.

Comment: Modern iPhones have two or three inbuilt microphones. The question states "two _iPhone_ microphones".